# How to get a key value and do some action with the value in a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, hashmap

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
        dp.setDayCellFactory(picker -> new DateCell() {
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

                setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(today) < 0 );

            }
        });
        /*This switch button will only allow to switch scenes if a date is selected*/
        Button swtich = new Button("Add other details");
        swtich.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                if (dp.getValue() == null)
                {
                    a.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                    a.setHeaderText("Enter a proper date !");
                    a.showAndWait();


                }
                else {
                    LocalDate localDate = dp.getValue();
                    stage01.setScene(scene01);
                }


            }
        });
```

**Now the localdate gets saved in the hashmap with seat number as soon as the user enters the other required details**

```
DateDetails.put(dp.getValue(),seatC);
```

**Now i want to compare this  date which is stored in DateDetails with a date picked up by the user . if its already stored in the hashmap then i want to get the seatC which is that seats and then disable the previous stored seats**

[This is the output i get when i save the required details in the hashmap,so everything is fine with the hashmap but i dont have an idea on how to compare the new chose date with the previous stored date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slmqi.png)

Comment: First off it would bbe great if you could clarify what the actual behavior is and post the other relevant code from your project rather than just a selection. But from what I can tell your issue is that you are checxking two strings that are formated different ways. Before your if statement print out everything you are comparing to see if its correct.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @TagHoward okay thank you ill try to check with that if statement and im pretty new to java so please bear with me, i really appreciate you helping me out in this.

Comment: @kleopatra yes sure

Comment: @TagHoward   heres the new piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.keySet()`? `.keySet()` gives you an array of the keys, and then you could iterate through that array of keys to do your desired operation.

For example, say you have a HashMap called food

```
food.put("apple", 1);
food.put("orange", 2):
```

Then you can just iterate through they keys by:

```
for(String k: food.keySet()) {
//do whatever
}
```